# Laravel '404 not found' error even after having a proper route?

Tags: php, laravel

Even after having a proper route set in my `web.php`, I am getting the `404 not found` error in my Laravel application in `local` mode.

[image]

All the pages are working correctly except this one and I am getting this error with `POST` method after clicking on `submit` button on the form. Here is my `web.php` file.

```
Route::get('categories/create',"CategoryController@create");
Route::post('categories',"CategoryController@store");
```

**UPDATE:**
My logs says:

```
[Wed Mar 21 16:40:22 2018] 127.0.0.1:59460 [404]: /categories - No such file or directory
[Wed Mar 21 16:40:22 2018] 127.0.0.1:59464 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Wed Mar 21 16:41:00 2018] 127.0.0.1:59472 [404]: /categories - No such file or directory
[Wed Mar 21 16:41:00 2018] 127.0.0.1:59476 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Wed Mar 21 16:41:03 2018] 127.0.0.1:59480 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Wed Mar 21 16:41:09 2018] 127.0.0.1:59484 [404]: /categories - No such file or directory
[Wed Mar 21 16:41:09 2018] 127.0.0.1:59488 [200]: /favicon.ico
```

Here is my View file -> https://pastebin.com/NEukzc5s

Comment: Check my answer below.

Comment: php artisan route:clear followed by change in /categories to url. Are you using resource in routes if Yes comment that thing and check again

Comment: Have you tried using a resource route instead of your two routes? `Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');`

Comment: Still same! @rahulsm

Comment: Would you like to share your view of create method?

Comment: Paste your form please, maybe missing a token or something

Comment: Sure! here we go -> https://pastebin.com/NEukzc5s

Comment: can you please check my answer

Comment: Try renaming your route, use another name instead of `/categories` just to check if it is because of the word

Comment: Your view looks good. please run 'php artisan route:list' and provide corresponding links.

Comment: @FirozAhmad, Error is solved. Please check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/49405031/3617661

Comment: Ok, that's great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may have same `categories` named directory in project's public folder. `(public/categories)`

Just rename that directory to some other name and try.

Comment: Worked! Thanks, brother! It's Eye-Opening stuff!

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities,

1. You may not wrote your route entry in `auth middleware` group
2. You should have used resource to specify which url specifies controller which is deprecated in latest laravel versions as you need to write route for every single actions you call.
3. You should always give `/` before start of every url
4. If all fine, then you should fire command `php artisan route:clear`

Check all these possibilities and let me know if error.

Comment: 1. It is written in the `auth middleware` group

Comment: Are you logged In ?

Comment: 3. i gave '/' before every route. Still same.

Comment: 2nd point mean you shouldn't have to use resource controller as it is deprecated

Comment: Yes, I am logged in brother. Obviously!

Comment: I am not using Resource controller brother.

Comment: Can you write echo in store method or have you checked there are no duplicate routes with same name?

Comment: change your route name like `Route::post('/categories/save',"CategoryController@store");` and check

Comment: @rahulsm Can you elaborate on 2. and 3. a little? Because [the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers) "still" mentions ResourceControllers and all the routes they have there do NOT start with `/`. Thx

Comment: Resource we mention in routes in previous version of laravel, where action name must start with get or post. and rest part of action name will be auto captured by laravel, so for that we dont need to write extra routes.
But in new versions you must write route for every action.
if you dont put / as first char of your url, then whatever parent url is there, will be appended with every url you call from that page.